# Put text on a new line when it overflows out of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I have tried loads of code put I can't get my text to go onto a new line. Here is the JS Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SfG8r/1/

Basically I want the text to go onto a new line (Just like a paragraph in a book) when it goes outside of the box.

HTML:

```
<div class='all1'>
<ol class='fs1' id='hide'>
    <li><p>Fs1</p></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TEST</a></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap .all1 {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 2em; left: 9em;  z-index: 600;}
.wrap #hide {display: block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; color: #222;}
.wrap #hide a {display: block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; color: #06C; font-weight: bold; font-size: 13px; display: table-cell; 
 height: 20px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: `new line` being the next column over...?

Comment: all text's show up on separate lines, are meaning something else? or do you mean you need the box to expand with more content?

Comment: If you're trying to get your single list to arrange itself into new columns, let me know. It's a tad tricky, but I just answered that the other day.

Comment: Yes sorry I am trying to get the text into a new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved! Here is my code: I have added this code to the div containing the text

CSS:

```
-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;
```